The relationship between different definitions of height
We know that for a rational number $x=a/b \in \mathbb Q$, its height is defined by
$$
\text{ht}(x)=\log\max\{|a|,|b|\}.
$$
For an algebraic number $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}^{\times}$ with $\operatorname{deg}(\alpha)=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha): \mathbb{Q}]$, let
$$
P_a(z)=a_{d} z^d+\cdots+a_1 z+a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[z]
$$
be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. The height of $\alpha$ is then defined by
$$
\text{ht}(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\deg(\alpha)}(\log a_d+\sum_{j=1}^d\log^+|\alpha_j|).
$$
Now let $X$ be a regular, projective, flat scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$, $Y \subset X$ be an integral closed subset, and $\bar L$ be an hermitian line bundle on $X$.
Theorem 2.13 in $\textit{Arakelov Geometry and Diophantine
Applications}$ (by Emmanuel Peyre) claims that there is a unique way to associate every $Y$ to a height $h_{\bar{L}}(Y) \in \mathbb{R}$ in such a way that:
(1) If $\operatorname{dim}(Y)=0$, i.e. when $Y=\{y\}$ where $y \in X$ is a closed point, we let $\kappa(y)=\mathscr{O}_{X, y} / \mathscr{M}_{X, y}$ be the residue field. Then $\kappa(y)$ is finite and
$$
h_{\bar{L}}(Y)=\log \#(\kappa(y)) .
$$
(2)  If $\operatorname{dim}(Y)>0$, let $s$ be a non-trivial rational section of $L$ over $Y$. If
$$
\operatorname{div}_Y(s)=\sum_\alpha n_\alpha Y_\alpha
$$
then
$$
h_{\bar{L}}(Y)=\sum_\alpha n_\alpha h_{\bar{L}}\left(Y_\alpha\right)-\int_{Y(\mathbf{C})} \log \|s\| c_1(\bar{L})^{\operatorname{dim} Y(\mathbf{C})}.
$$
I wonder if this is equivalent to the definition of the usual height for rational numbers and algebraic numbers. But I'm not familiar with algebraic geometry over $\mathbb{Z}$.
On the other hand, I know there are various kinds of heights, so how is the uniqueness in this theorem reflected?
